# Delete Cells while removing reference errors

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i would like to delete cells while removing reference errors simultaneously but my code does not seem to work. It deletes cells but not the reference errors. Need help on this.  Thank you very much!

```
Sub DeleteCells()


    Dim rngError As Range
    Dim R As Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)
     Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
     On Error GoTo 0
     'delete means cells will move up after deleting that entire row
     'rngError.EntireRow.ClearContents means that the contents will clear, leaving a blank cell for that entire row

   If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    R.Delete
     For Each cell In Range("A1:Z100")
   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
     rngError.Delete

End If

Next

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: If you are getting a `#REF!` error because an offset or something similar is trying to reference a cell off the worksheet (e.g. `=offset($C$3, -5, -10)` then clear those cells; do not delete them. If you delete them and the cells below shift up, the formulas in those cells now have the same problem. Similarly, if another cell is referencing a cell you delete, it now has a `#REF!` error.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete formula errors in Column A

```
Sub del_err()
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error GoTo er
    Set rng = Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Exit Sub
    End If
er:     MsgBox "No errors found"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Niva- you are supposed to reply to comments and answers.